# Xcode 8.0 ios10 Build Warning for Core-Plot Bar Chart

Tags: core-plot, ios10

I have an existing project, written in objective-C, from ios8 with the Core-Plot 1.5.1 Static Library. I am compiling for ios8.2->ios10 using Xcode 8.0 beta 6 (8S201h).

When I compile the project I receive the following warning. 
(The app creates my bar chart just fine when it runs.)

> WARNING: Assigning to  _Nullable from incompatible
>   type 'myViewController * const_strong'

In my bar chart view controller, I have the following:

in the .h:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <CPTBarPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

in the .m:

```
 CPTBarPlot *barPlot = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init];

 barPlot.dataSource = self;

 barPlot.delegate = self; // [Warning: occurs on this line]
```

Any advice you might have on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry the code doesn't print correctly above. in the .h:  It omits line @interface myViewController : UIViewController <CPTBarPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>

Comment: The warning should read:WARNING:
Assigning to <CALayerDelegate> _Nullable from incompatible type 'myViewController * const_strong'

Answer (score 2):

Branch `release-2.2` contains fixes which solves this kind of issues. It's not officially released but you can try to checkout to see what changes have been made. [Link](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/commits/release-2.2)

Comment: Core Plot release 2.2 should be out soon after the final release of Xcode 8.

Comment: azimov and @EricSkroch thank you for your posts. I'll upgrade to Core Plot 2.2 when it's released. In the interim, I'll look at the changes I need to make to my chart controllers.